# URLSpans in WebView?

Tags: android, android-webview, textview

I need to push text into WebView. But there are a lot of different HTML tags in this text and I want to parse it before.

```java
Spanned html = Html.fromHtml(texts.get(i));
```

But I need to change URLs in the text to call one function in my activity. In TextView I may do it like that:

```java
ClickableSpan[] items = spans.getSpans(0, spans.length(), ClickableSpan.class);
for (ClickableSpan s : items) {
    final String url = ((URLSpan)s).getURL();
    int spanStart = spans.getSpanStart(s);
    int spanEnd = spans.getSpanEnd(s);
    spans.removeSpan(s);
    spans.setSpan(new URLSpan(url) {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View widget) {
            //code for overriding onClick goes here            
        }
    }, spanStart, spanEnd, Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
}
```

Is it possible to use Html.fromHTML() AND to change links in text to call my function when using WebView instead of TextView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not really, because `WebView` understands HTML, not a `Spanned`. You are welcome to try to convert the `Spanned` back into HTML via `Html.toHtml()`, but the round-trip conversion from HTML to `Spanned` to HTML is likely to make a hash of any complex formatting, because they are not complete HTML parsers or generators.

I would recommend that you find and use some Java library that is designed to parse and help you fix up HTML.